# Pig fails to store data into HIVE table using HCAT

Tags: linux, hive, apache-pig, hadoop2, hcatalog

Pig fails to store data into HIVE table using HCatStorer() when the same table hold 998/999 number of files.

When i merge all these files to a single one, the ERROR disappears and again appears when the file count reaches 998/999.

I just use this table as a warehouse where i store new dataset along with the old ones.

Please let me know is there any way to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the error message to your question ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how does HCat name the output file? Just in case it's something like `blahblah001`...

Comment: /user/hive/warehouse/hist_msisdn_table_tmp/part-r-00000
/user/hive/warehouse/hist_msisdn_table_tmp/part-r-00000_a_1
/user/hive/warehouse/hist_msisdn_table_tmp/part-r-00000_a_10
/user/hive/warehouse/hist_msisdn_table_tmp/part-r-00000_a_100
/user/hive/warehouse/hist_msisdn_table_tmp/part-r-00000_a_101
.


@SamsonScharfrichter